# How to sum case when X=Y group by Y?

Tags: mysql, sum, case-when

I'm trying to write a query that says iff an ID exists in `all1o1s` and in `SC.salesforce_id`, then sum the number of times it exists in `all1o1s`.

I wrote:

```
select 
   sc.salesforce_id,
   sum(case when all1o1s.member_id = sc.salesforce_id then 1 else 0) as "1o1 completed count"
from salesforce_contacts as sc 
inner join leenk_1o1s as all1o1s on sc.salesforce_id = all1o1s.member_id    
group by sc.salesforce_id;
```

I'm getting an error at the sum line. How do I structure this query?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ` ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as "1o1 completed count"


from salesforce_contacts as sc
 inner join leenk_1o' at line 2`

Comment: The specific syntax error is because you don't have an end statement at the end of the case statement. However, the sql you wrote probably won't accomplish your objective.

Comment: @sam thanks very much. Any thoughts on the syntax that will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 select b.salesforce_id,count(1) from all1o1s a,salesforce_contacts b where a.id=b.salesforce_id
group by b.salesforce_id having count(1) > 1
```

As per your question you need count not sum

Comment: Thank you!! This is it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually - I thought that it was it, but I don't think it is. It should return counts greater than 1, but it's not. 

I made a slight adjustment: 

`select b.salesforce_id,
count(1) as '1 on 1 count'

from leenk_1o1s a,salesforce_contacts b 

where a.id=b.salesforce_id
group by b.salesforce_id

order by '1 on 1 count' desc
;`

But still am not getting the right count. Thoughts?

Comment: Getting 0 records w/ that. 

Also tried: 

`select b.salesforce_id,
count(1) as "1 on 1 count"
from leenk_1o1s a,salesforce_contacts b where a.id=b.salesforce_id
group by b.salesforce_id having count(1) >= 1

order by "1 on 1 count" desc;`

But still not getting a count great than 1 when I'd expect it

Comment: check this sqlfiddle its working fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83114e3/1

Comment: Ahh! Caught it. in my table, id = member_id :D

Comment: Ok, one more question. If I want to add another column... do I shift count(1) to count (2)? I'm not sure the role that the (#) is playing.

Comment: use count(1) only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179115/discussion-between-alissa-swartz-and-vinay-chhabra).